# Error in Fetch: "Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResults>'"

Tags: ios, swift

Using this function to sort my cells in my table view. I am getting an error in my fetch request. The line inside of the do loop,  `notes = try context.fetch(request)` is causing the error , the request is underlined

The error says "Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest'"

## My TableViewController file

```
 import UIKit
import CoreData
 

class noteTableViewController: UITableViewController {
 
    var notes = [Note]()

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? {
 
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
 
    }
 

    func loadDataFromDatabase() {
 
        let settings = UserDefaults.standard

        let sortPriority = settings.string(forKey: Constants.kPriority)

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Note")

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortPriority)

        let sortDescriptorsArray = [sortDescriptor]

        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorsArray

        do {
 
            notes = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch let errer as NSError {
 
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

 
    }

 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func loadDataFromDatabase() {
  ...

  let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Note")

  ...

  do {
    notes = try context.fetch(request) as? [Note] ?? []
  } catch let errer as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
}
```

Of course, I'm assuming your `Note` class is a subclass of `NSManagerObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it as an array of Notes

```
  do {
    notes = try context.fetch(request) as? [Note] ?? []
  } catch let errer as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
```